# F# Is it possible to have an interface implement an interface?

Tags: inheritance, interface, f#

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
type face1 = 
    interface
    // ...
    end

type face2 =
    interface
    // ...
    interface face1 with
    // ...
    end
```

Such that anything that interfaces face2 can also be considered a face1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to implement an interface, but you can have one interface inherit another:

```
type face1 = 
    interface
    end

type face2 =
    interface
        inherit face1
    end
```

This way implementors would need to provide `face1` implementation in addition to whatever `face2` asks for.